# GitHub: How to create a pull request that results in a new branch?

Tags: git, github

We want to be able to pull (using a pull request) unfinished feature branches on GitHub.

Workflow:

- A user forks a GitHub repo.
- They create a feature branch, commit some changes, and issue a pull request.
- Is there any way with GitHub to pull the branch reference?

Said differently, my colleagues and I would like to be able to create pull requests that result not in a merge, but in the feature branch existing in the upstream repo.

How to do a pull request that does this (from the upstream maintainer's point-of-view):

```
$ git clone UPSTREAM_REPO upstream
$ cd upstream
upstream$ git fetch USER_REPO feature_branch
upstream$ git push origin FETCH_HEAD:refs/heads/feature_branch
```

Comment: You can't use pull requests for that. Is your question on how to do this client side (interacting with multiple remote) or specifically about doing this with pull requests?

Comment: @SébastienDawans Specifically using the GitHub website. That way we can use their tooling. I guess we'll create pull requests and use the review tools and then pull the branches manually while closing/canceling the request.